# Parquet compression degradation when upgrading spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, snappy

I have a spark job that writes data to parquet files with snappy compression.
One of the columns in parquet is a repeated INT64.

When upgrading from spark 2.2 with parquet 1.8.2 to spark 3.1.1 with parquet 1.10.1, I witnessed a severe degradation in compression ratio.

For [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZx_qAmoX1HDpAVplvFnl2iC83siOCTE/view?usp=sharing) for example (saved with spark 2.2) I have the following metadata:

```
creator:     parquet-mr version 1.8.2 (build c6522788629e590a53eb79874b95f6c3ff11f16c) 
extra:       org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata = {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"numbers","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"long","containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]} 

file schema: spark_schema 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
numbers:     OPTIONAL F:1 
.list:       REPEATED F:1 
..element:   OPTIONAL INT64 R:1 D:3

row group 1: RC:186226 TS:163626010 OFFSET:4 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
numbers:     
.list:       
..element:    INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:79747617/163626010/2.05 VC:87158527 ENC:RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[min: 4, max: 1967324, num_nulls: 39883]
```

Reading it with spark 3.1 and saving it again as parquet, I get the following metadata, and parquet part size increases from 76MB to 124MB:

```
creator:     parquet-mr version 1.10.1 (build a89df8f9932b6ef6633d06069e50c9b7970bebd1) 
extra:       org.apache.spark.version = 3.1.1 
extra:       org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata = {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"numbers","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"long","containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]} 

file schema: spark_schema 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
numbers:     OPTIONAL F:1 
.list:       REPEATED F:1 
..element:   OPTIONAL INT64 R:1 D:3

row group 1: RC:186226 TS:163655597 OFFSET:4 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
numbers:     
.list:       
..element:    INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:129657160/163655597/1.26 VC:87158527 ENC:RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[min: 4, max: 1967324, num_nulls: 39883]
```

Note the compression ratio decreased from `2.05` to `1.26`.

Tried looking for any configuration that have changed between spark or parquet versions. The only thing I could find is `parquet.writer.max-padding` changed from `0` to `8MB`, but even when changing this configuration back to `0`, I get the same results.

Below is the ParquetOutputFormat configuration I have with both setups:

```
Parquet block size to 134217728
Parquet page size to 1048576
Parquet dictionary page size to 1048576
Dictionary is on
Validation is off
Writer version is: PARQUET_1_0
Maximum row group padding size is 0 bytes
Page size checking is: estimated
Min row count for page size check is: 100
Max row count for page size check is: 10000
```

I would appreciate any guidance here.

Thanks!

### UPDATE

Checked spark 3 with snappy 1.1.2.6 (used by spark 2.2), and the compression ratio looks good.
Will further look into this issue, and update on my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as updated above, snappy-java 1.1.2.6 resolved my issue.
Any version higher than this, results in degraded compression. Also tried the [purejava](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java#using-pure-java-snappy-implementation) flag, but this results in Exception reading parquet.
Will open tickets for snappy-java